# How can I generate Java classes from a WSDL

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I'm developing an android app and I'm connecting it to a web service. I need to generate the complex data types that were declared in the WSDL and use them in `Eclipse`.

How can I do that? I've tried downloading this http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/ but I'm not sure how to use it! Also, am i supposed to download axis 1.4?
Help plz

Answer (score 0):

there is wsimport tool in jdk.
just run

```
wsimport yourFile.wsdl --keep
```

[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) is documentation on this tool

Comment: can you please explain how to use it in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Steps :

**First Open This Site** [WSDL](http://www.wsdl2code.com/)

**Then Upload your wsdl File To website / OR Give link to your WSDL web service**

**Download Your Java Classes Related To Your WSDL Web Service**

Hope this Helps...

Comment: thanks but where should i download the java classes to? how can I use it in eclipse?

Comment: you can directly download the java classes & use that into your project as required...

Comment: would you mind telling me how to directly download it? I've uploaded my wsdl to the site you gave me, downloaded the file that it generated to my computer , but now how can i use this file into eclipse? sorry I'm a beginner in this, thank u for ur help

Comment: r u taking about project structure ?

Comment: no just how to import the classes that I've downloaded into eclipse and use it

Comment: simply make the `package` & name it as the downloaded file consist the structure like `com\Wsdl2Code\WebServices\YourServce_name` & then put all the downloaded class into that package related to that services.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57924/discussion-between-user3792722-and-i-n-e-f).